# How to pass data from adapter to fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've been trying to pass data(the email and phone of a user) from my adapter to my fragment. From what I've read online I should use a interface for this but I cant the data into my fragment still. Can anyone explain in steps how I should add a interface and how to put data into my interface from my adapter so I can call it in my fragment. Or is there another way to pass data from my adapter to my fragment. Below are my adapter and my fragment.

Adapter:

```
package ie.wit.savvytutor.adapters
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import ie.wit.savvytutor.R
import ie.wit.savvytutor.activity.MainActivity
import ie.wit.savvytutor.fragments.ViewChatFragment
import ie.wit.savvytutor.models.UserModel


class UserAdapter(private val userList: ArrayList<UserModel>, val context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
    val itemView =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.user_layout, parent, false)
    return UserViewHolder(itemView)
}


class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val username: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userNameView)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int, ) {
    val currentItem = userList[position]



    holder.username.text = currentItem.email
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        println(currentItem)

        




        val optionsFrag = ViewChatFragment()
        (context as MainActivity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, optionsFrag, "OptionsFragment").addToBackStack(
                null
            )
            .commit()
    }


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size

}
```

}

Fragment

```
package ie.wit.savvytutor.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup    
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import ie.wit.savvytutor.R
import ie.wit.savvytutor.adapters.UserAdapter
import ie.wit.savvytutor.models.UserModel

class TutorChatFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var userRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var userArrayList: ArrayList<UserModel>
private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("DATABASE LINK").getReference("Users").ref
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}

@Nullable
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
    @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    //inflate the fragment layout
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutor_chat_fragment, container, false)
    userRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.userListView)
    userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    userRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


    userArrayList = arrayListOf<UserModel>()
    getUser()
    return root
}

private fun getUser() {

    userArrayList.clear()

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val currentUser = postSnapshot.getValue(UserModel::class.java)

                //BUG FIX 1.26.13

                val email = currentUser?.email
                if (email != null) {
                    userArrayList.add(currentUser)
                }

                userRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                userRecyclerView.adapter = context?.let { UserAdapter(userArrayList, it) }

            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an interface, you just need to define one with a function to receive your data, make the fragment implement it, then pass the fragment to the adapter as an implementation of that interface:

```
data class UserData(val email: String, val phone: String)

class UserAdapter(
    private val userList: ArrayList<UserModel>,
    val context: Context,
    val handler: UserAdapter.Callbacks // added this here, so you're passing it in at construction
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    ...

    private fun doWhatever(email: String, phone: String) {
        // pass the data to the handler (which will probably be your Fragment)
        handler.handleUserData(UserData(email, phone))
    }

    // nested inside the UserAdapter class to keep things tidy
    interface Callbacks {
        fun handleUserData(data: UserData)
    }
}
```

Then in the Fragment:

```
// add the Callbacks interface type
class TutorChatFragment : Fragment(), UserAdapter.Callbacks {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
        @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        ...
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        // set up the adapter here, passing this fragment as the Callbacks handler
        userRecyclerView.adapter = UserAdapter(userArrayList, context, this)
        ...
    }

    // interface implementation
    override fun handleUserData(data: UserData) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

And that's it. You're not hardcoding a dependency on that particular Fragment type, just the interface, and this fragment implements it so it can pass itself.

---

A more Kotliny way to do it is to ignore interfaces and just pass a function instead

```
class UserAdapter(
    private val userList: ArrayList<UserModel>,
    val context: Context,
    val handler: (UserData) -> Unit // passing a function that takes a UserData instead
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    ...

    private fun doWhatever(email: String, phone: String) {
        // call the handler function with your data (you can write handler.invoke() if you prefer)
        handler(UserData(email, phone))
    }
}
```

```
// no interface this time
class TutorChatFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
        @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        ...
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        // pass in a handler function
        userRecyclerView.adapter = UserAdapter(userArrayList, context) { userData ->
            handleUserData(userData)
        }
        // or if you're just passing it to that function down there,
        // you could do UserAdapter(userArrayList, context, ::handleUserData)
        // and pass the function reference
        ...
    }

    // might be convenient to still do this in its own function
    private fun handleUserData(data: UserData) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

---

Ideally you should be doing what I've done there - create the adapter *once* during setup, and have a function on it that allows you to update it. Your code creates a new one each time you get data. You do this the same way in both though

Your other option is using a view model that the adapter and fragment both have access to, but this is how you do the interface/callback approach

Comment: Using the more kotlin liked way worked perfectly thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one very easy way to get data from your adapter in to your fragment or activity. It is called using Higher Order Functions.
**In your adapter**
Add higher order function in your adapter.

```
class UserAdapter(private val userList: ArrayList<UserModel>, val context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {
//your rest of the adapter's code

private var onItemClickListener:((UserModel)->Unit)? = null
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (UserModel)->Unit) {
     onItemClickListener = listener
   }
}
```

**In Your UserViewHolder**

```
val rootView = itemView.rootView
```

**In Your onBindViewHolder**
set a click listener on rootView

```
holder.rootView.setOnClickListener {
   onItemClickListener?.let{
          it(currentItem)
    }
}
```

**In Your Fragment**

```
//create the instance of UserAdapter
userAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
  //here you have your UserModel in your fragment, do whatever you want to with it
}
```

And, a suggestion in the last. Start using ViewBinding, it will save you from a lots of hectic work.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately when trying to add the last part into my fragment the option for .setOnItemClick does not appear!

Comment: Then check for 2 things. 
First, setOnItemClickListener must me be in your adapter class body.
Second, It should not be private.