# How to pass data from RecyclerView's click listener to another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my program, I have a RecyclerView with an adapter, in which I'm checking which element of RecyclerView is clicked.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentBreakfast = breakfastList[position]
    holder.breakfastTitle.text = context.getText(currentBreakfast.breakfastStringResourceId)
    holder.breakfastImage.setImageResource(currentBreakfast.breakfastImageResourceId)

    holder.breakfastImage.setOnClickListener {
        holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_breakfastFragment_to_DetailsFragment)
        showDetails(currentBreakfast)
    }
}
```

I want to pass the data about specific clicked element, such as **imageId**, **stringId**, **Name**, etc. to another fragment **DetailsFragment** in which I would like to display further data

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your fragment to the adapter from where you are calling i guess it's breakfastFragment, just add `this` to it:

```
            BreakfastAdapter(
                requireActivity(),
                breakfastList,
                this
            )
```

And your Adapter get that `fragment`:

```
open class BreakfastAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var breakfastList: ArrayList<Breakfast>,
    private val fragment: Fragment
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

And you can use that `fragment` to be able to navigate from it:

```
holder.breakfastImage.setOnClickListener {
// create a bundle to hold data you want to send
 val bundle = bundleOf(
   "breakfastImageResourceId" to currentBreakfast.breakfastImageResourceId,
   "breakfastStringResourceId" to currentBreakfast.breakfastStringResourceId,
   "kcal" to currentBreakfast.kcal
 )
// add this bundle when you move to another fragment.              
fragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_breakfastFragment_to_DetailsFragment, bundle)
}
```

In another fragment get that value and see them in the Log like below:

```
// create below variables
private var mBreakfastImageResourceId: Int = 0
private var mBreakfastStringResourceId: Int = 0
private var mKcal: Int = 0

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Now we set above values with what we sent from adapter
        arguments?.let {
            if (it["breakfastImageResourceId"] != null) {
                mBreakfastImageResourceId = it.getInt("BreakfastImageResourceId")!!
            }
            if (it["breakfastStringResourceId"] != null) {
                mBreakfastStringResourceId = it.getInt("breakfastStringResourceId")!!
            }
            if (it["kcal"] != null) {
                mKcal = it.getInt("kcal")!!
            }
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_stats, container, false)
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // now you can do whatever you want with mBreakfastImageResourceId, mBreakfastStringResourceId and mKcal.

}
```

P.S. I just made up some variable and class names because you did not share them, just change it with yours correct ones.

Comment: could you show, how to use the variables in the fragment, instead of just displaying them into the log?

Comment: If you manage to do that, it's easy to use that variables in your entire new fragment. I edited my answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to it.

I suggest you have a look at this answer (the accepted one) :
[How to pass data from adapter to fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888926/how-to-pass-data-from-adapter-to-fragment)

And then go to the section called "A more Kotlin way to do it is to ignore interfaces and just pass a function instead".

This is the approach I also use myself.

Here is an exampe of how my Adapter for the RecyclerView is defined:

```
class ReportAdapter(var reports: List<Report>,val clickFunc : (Report) -> (Unit)) :  RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ViewHolder>() {...}
```

Then you need to attach the callback function to a click listener inside your viewholder - in my example it looks like this (every item in the list has a cardview - defined in the xml file):

```
itemView.report_cardview_item.setOnClickListener {
                clickFunc(report)
            }
```

Then in the callback function you pass to the RecylerView Adapter you can navigate to a details fragment with the relevant data - one of my callback functions (which is passed to the Adapter upon creation) simply looks like this (defined in the Fragment that "owns" the RecyclerView):

```
private fun reportClicked(report:Report)
    {
        val action = ReportsFragmentDirections.actionNavReportsToReportDetailFragment(report)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

(here using my navigation graph to create an Action to use for the NavController)

My adapter is easily initialized with some data and a reference to the callback function:

```
   adapter = ReportAdapter(reports,::reportClicked)
```

Comment: I don't fully get it, could you please provide more code?

Comment: Nicely done.  I'm really not a fan of passing big entities like fragments down. Lambdas are a really nice solution.