# How to trigger change in Fragment based on item in focus in RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, listener

I have a FireTv app and need to trigger a TextView change in my fragment based on the item in focus in my adapter. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888926/how-to-pass-data-from-adapter-to-fragment#:%7E:text=Actually%20there%20is%20one%20very,order%20function%20in%20your%20adapter.) which is basically what I'm looking for except it needs to be based on what is in focus not clicked. I don't see a "setOnItemFocusListener." Does anyone know how I could make this work with focus instead of click?

Comment: I had an experience in making a fireTV application but now i'm so busy to write some sample code for you and it is my try to help you.
 you can use setFocusable for your view and then use setOnFocusChangeListener to be able to control the focus and the appearance of your view. So set this flag to true for your items of your Recyclerview then pass a lambda to your Adapter from your fragment and call it when one of the item's `onFocusChangeListener` called. that's all.

Comment: That did work, but adding setOnFocusChangeListener to the root view in my onBindViewHolder has stopped the onFocusChangeListener in my ViewHolder from being called and now the itemView no longer animates.